# Swift closure is using a stale value even though it's @escaping

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my SwiftUI app I have a `TappableView` struct which wraps an `UITapGestureRecognizer` and takes an `action` parameter which is an `@escaping` closure.
I also have a custom HStack struct. When I use these structs together and trigger a state change, the action closure becomes stale, even though the views are correctly redrawn. When I use these classes separately I don't have this issue. I am pretty sure I'm using `@escaping` everywhere I should be, but I just can't figure this issue out.

To reproduce this issue run the code below, then click "Swap items", then click any of the top two buttons - the wrong value will be printed.

In my app these classes have custom logic which I've removed in this minimal reproducible example.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

func nextValue() -> Int {
    Int.random(in: 1..<99)
}

class Item : Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    @Published var value : Int
    
    init(value : Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class ItemArray : ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [ Item(value: nextValue()), Item(value: nextValue()) ]
}

class Log : ObservableObject {
    @Published var log = ""
}

struct ItemView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item : Item
    let action: (Item) -> Void
    
    init(item: Item, action: @escaping (Item) -> Void) {
        self.item = item
        self.action = action
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("\(item.value)") {
            action(item)
        }
        .frame(width: 30)
        .padding(5)
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}

struct LogView: View {
    @ObservedObject var log : Log
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(log.log)
        .padding(5)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var items = ItemArray()
    @StateObject var log = Log()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Swap items") {
                items.items.swapAt(0, 1)
            }
            .padding(5)
            
            Text("CustomHStack + TappableView - doesn't work")
                .padding(.top, 5)
            CustomHStack(items.items, id: \.self) { item in
                return TappableView(action: {
                    log.log += "item: \(item.value)\n"
                }, tapView: {
                    Text("\(item.value)")
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .padding(5)
                        .border(Color.black)

                })
            }
            .padding(5)
            .border(Color.black)

            Text("HStack + ItemView - does work")
                .padding(.top, 5)
            HStack() {
                ForEach(items.items) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item, action: { itemArg in
                        log.log += "item: \(item.value) "
                        log.log += "itemArg: \(itemArg.value)\n"
                    })
                }
            }
            .padding(5)
            .border(Color.black)

            Text("CustomHStack + ItemView - does work")
                .padding(.top, 5)
            CustomHStack(items.items, id: \.self) { item in
                ItemView(item: item, action: { itemArg in
                    log.log += "item: \(item.value) "
                    log.log += "itemArg: \(itemArg.value)\n"
                })
            }
            .padding(5)
            .border(Color.black)
            
            Text("HStack + TappableView - does work")
                .padding(.top, 5)
            HStack() {
                ForEach(items.items) { item in
                    return TappableView(action: {
                        log.log += "item: \(item.value)\n"
                    }, tapView: {
                        Text("\(item.value)")
                            .frame(width: 30)
                            .padding(5)
                            .border(Color.black)
                    })
                }
            }
            .padding(5)
            .border(Color.black)
            
            LogView(log:log)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct TappableView<TapView: View> : View {
    public let action: () -> Void
    @ViewBuilder var tapView: () -> TapView
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, tapView: @escaping () -> TapView) {
        self.action = action
        self.tapView = tapView
    }

    var body: some View {
        tapView()
        .overlay(
            TappableViewRepresentable(action: action)
        )
    }
}

private struct TappableViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let action: () -> Void

    init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }
    
    typealias UIViewType = UIView

    func makeCoordinator() -> TappableViewRepresentable.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(action: action)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator,
                                                          action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Self.Context) { }

    class Coordinator {
        let action: () -> Void

        init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.action = action
        }

        @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            guard sender.state == .ended else { return }
            action()
        }
    }
}

public struct CustomHStack: View {
    let items: [AnyView]

    init<Data: RandomAccessCollection, Content: View>(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, Data.Element> = \.self, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.items = data.map { AnyView(content($0[keyPath: id])) }
    }

    public var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ... items.count - 1, id: \.self) { index in
               items[index]
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestClosureApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you did not implement `updateUIView` correctly. In `updateUIView`, you should update the `action` in the coordinator.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Self.Context) { 
    context.coordinator.action = action
}
```

This will be called when the items are swapped.

`updateUIView` doesn't have to work correctly for the `HStack` + `TappableView` combination to work, because in your `HStack` code, the `ForEach` uses each item's `id` as the identity of the views.

```
HStack() {
    ForEach(items.items) { item in
        TappableView(...)//.id(item.id)
    }
}
```

whereas in `CustomHStack`, the IDs are always the same - the first view always have id 0, the second always have id 1, and so on.

```
ForEach(0 ... items.count - 1, id: \.self) { index in
   items[index]//.id(index)
}
```

Therefore, the `ForEach` in `HStack` can see that these two views are swapped, This causes SwiftUI to directly swap the two `UIView`s, and so produces the expected behaviour.

The `ForEach` in `CustomHStack` however, cannot see this. It just updates the two `TappableView`s, and in turn causes `TappableViewRepresentable.updateUIView` to be called, but you did nothing in that method.

---

Side note: I would recommend avoiding `AnyView` in your `CustomHStack`. Instead, write something similar to `ForEach`, and make use of the `id` parameter - use that as the `id:` for `ForEach`:

```
public struct CustomHStack<Data: RandomAccessCollection, ID: Hashable, Content: View>: View {
    let data: Data
    let id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>
    let content: (Data.Element) -> Content

    init(data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content) {
        self.data = data
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
    }
    
    init(data: Data, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content) where Data.Element: Identifiable, ID == Data.Element.ID {
        self.data = data
        self.id = \.id
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(data, id: id) { elem in
               content(elem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could upvote your answer 100 times!